# Buffering the next song using a second AVPlayer

Tags: swift, avplayer

I want to play a list of songs but due to a custom queue system I don't want to use `AVQueuePlayer`, to have a seamless transition between songs (not having to wait for the next song to load/buffer) I want to create a second player which loads the next song in the queue and assign it to the main player, is it a legit solution?

Something like this:

```
var player = AVPlayer()
var nextSongPlayer = AVPlayer()
//...
func playSong() {
   let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: "URL1")
   player.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
   //...
   let player = AVPlayerItem(url: "URL2")
   nextSongPlayer.replaceCurrentItem(with: player)
   //...
   player.play()
}

func nextSong() {
   player = nextSongPlayer
   player = play
}
```

Or I should create an `AVPlayerItem` with the second URL and replace the current plying item with that? or there is a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is almost wright, I had tp create a new `AVPlayer` and assign it to the `nextSongPlayer`:

```
//...
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: "URL2")
let tempPlayer = AVPlayer()
tempPlayer.replaceCurrentItem(with: player)
tempPlayer.play() // Makes the player buffer the song
tempPlayer.pause() 
self. nextSongPlayer = tempPlayer()
//...
```